# How we compare two paragraphs of unlabelled dataset semantically (STS)?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, unsupervised-learning, semantic-similarity

Column representation: **Unique_id | Text1 | Text2**

**Unique_id** 0

**Text1** public show for reynolds suspension of his coaching licence. portrait sir joshua reynolds portrait of omai will get a public airing following fears it would stay hidden because of an export wrangle.

**Text2** then requested to do so by spain s anti-violence commission. the fine was far less than the expected amount of about Â£22 000 or even the suspension of his coaching licence.

**Unique_id** 1

**Text1** groening. gervais has already begun writing the script but is keeping its subject matter a closely guarded secret. he will also write a part for himself in the episode. i ve got the rough idea but this is the most intimidating project of my career.

**Text2** philadelphia said they found insufficient evidence to support the woman s allegations regarding an alleged incident in january 2004. the woman reported the allegations to canadian authorities last month. cosby s lawyer walter m phillips jr said the comedian was pleased with the decision.

In the above problem, I've to **compare two paragraphs texts** i.e. Text1 & Text2 and then I've to compare semantic similarity between two texts. If they are **semantically similar then it will print '1' if not then '0'**

Any refrence implementation link or any suggestions !

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve trough the exemple provided. Please try to elaborate on your goal.

Comment: I can't draw here tabular coloumns that's why In the very first line i've written the dataset representation is in the form :  Unique_id  | Text1  | Text2.                                        And, Unique_id, Text1, Text2   value is in the columns.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve from the exemple you gave.

Comment: Basically I've to perform Semantic Textual Similarity in the above problem and it is unlabelled dataset.          
I've to compare two paragraphs texts i.e. Text1 & Text2 and then I've to compare semantic similarity between two texts. If they are semantically similar then it will print '1' if not then '0'.

Comment: Yeah, but what do you call 'semantical similarity' ?

Comment: More precisely I have a hard time to see if the algo should output 0 or 1 on your exemple.

Comment: Semantic similarity means grouping similar words into semantic concepts into concepts that have the same meaning - appear to have the same meaning.

Comment: algo not give exact output either '0' or '1' , the output value lie between 0 to 1 for each row  then, we put some some threshold value regarding that inaccordance with that  threshold value the output is '0' or '1'.

Comment: Please give us a link or something... you are talking about very advanced concepts without any hint towards practical implementation. It gives the idea that you don't know what you are talking about or that you expect us to do your research work (or both).